# Problema al enviar datos a una bd PostgreSQL con Symfony4

Tags: sql, postgresql, symfony4, base-de-datos

El error que sale es el siguiente:

> An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT NEXTVAL('usuario_id_seq')':
>   SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR: no existe la relación «usuario_id_seq»
>   LINE 1: SELECT NEXTVAL('usuario_id_seq')

Nota:

Este error me sale cada vez que importo tablas de la bd y genero las entidades, cuando migro las entidades a la bd no me da este error, comparé ambas entidades(una migrada y una importada) y no encuentro alguna diferencia, si alguien sabe cómo resolverlo se lo agradecería mucho!

```
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")
 * @ORM\SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="usuario_id_seq", allocationSize=1, initialValue=1)
 */
private $id;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que crear una secuencia en postgreSQL ya que tu id es un autoincremental
para crearla puedes hacer lo siguiente en una terminal:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE usuario_id_seq START 1 INCREMENT BY 1;
```

O de forma grafica en tu pgAdmin:

[image: Abrir la el menu de secuencias]

[image: Poner un nombre de secuencia]

[image: Definir la secuencia]

Comment: Gracias, me sirvió por completo!!

Comment: me alegra que funcionara, Saludos!